# Vim Python indentation not working?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I have [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) 7 (enhanced) on CentOS 5, and it comes with all the usual Vim plugins/scripts ready to go.

```
$ find /usr/share/vim/vim70/ -name \*python\*
/usr/share/vim/vim70/syntax/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim70/ftplugin/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim70/indent/python.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim70/autoload/pythoncomplete.vim
```

I would think that when opening a file ending in .py (`vim file.py`) it would automatically load these plugins, but I am not sure that is the case. What I want is:

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and receive four spaces. Auto indent next line for suites, conditionals, etc.

I have this working by explicitly setting tabstop, shiftwidth, etc. in my .vimrc file. Isn't this what the above [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) files are for? Why do I have to set these things in my `.vimrc`? How do I get these features from the Vim plugins instead?

Current .vimrc:

```
syntax on
set hls
set expandtab
set textwidth=0
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set ruler
set wildmenu
set smarttab
filetype indent on
filetype on
filetype plugin on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting tabstop, shiftwidth, etc...  in your vimrc is correct. These set your global settings, as well as serve as parameters to the filetype-specific indentation support.

The language indentation plugins use these settings, but typically also set an indent expression (`:he inde`) appropriate for the language. Thus the Python indenter should be automatically indenting after a block opening statement (def, class, for...), and dedenting after a closing one (return, pass, continue...) and doing so according to the ts,sw,... you have set.

If you're still unsure if the plugin is loading for a buffer, simply do `:filetype` to show the detection, plugin, and indent settings, and `:set ft?` to see the detected type.

Comment: So to summarize the ../indent/python.vim file is not capable of setting the tabstop, shiftwidth, etc for me...so they must be specified within the vimrc? What happens if I wanted tabstop to be different depending on filetype? Can I place these vimrc settings in the indent/python.vim file so as to only have them load for python files?

Comment: You could add those settings to indent/python.vim and get that result, but a better way would be to add filetype specific settings as autocmds that will run after a buffer is loaded. (:he au)

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that the python.vim file is just a syntax-highlighting file possibly, because Python files can be indented multiple ways. [PEP8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Development) prescribes four spaces, but legacy files could be different including using tabs.

Some of our legacy Python files actually use two spaces per indent. So I leave Python indenting to Vim and configure it per file and per filetype. The following line in .vimrc gives me Python-specific settings which differ from say my xml, xhtml, and html (two spaces).

```
au FileType python setl shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
```

You can also set specific settings by file with a [modeline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) which is handy if you do have legacy files.

```
# vi: set tabstop=2 expandtab textwidth=70 filetype=python:
```