# How to halve the number of whitespace at the beginning of each line in Vim?

Tags: vim, removing-whitespace

Can someone tell me how to do the opposite of this mapping in Vim:

```
nnoremap <leader>iw :let _s=@/<Bar>:let _s2=line(".")<Bar>:%s/^\s*/&&/ge<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar>:nohl<Bar>exe ':'._s2<CR>
```

As a clarification: This mapping doubles (the `&&` part) the number of whitespace characters at the beginning of each line.
Only the whitespace before the first regular character is affected.
Current search string is kept in tact (via the `_s` variable).
The cursor position is restored after this transformation (via the `_s2` variable).

So, basically, I’m searching for a mapping that will undo this one if they are executed one after another.

I’m having trouble in figuring out how to limit this new operation to work only on whitespace before the first regular character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following substitute command inverses the effect of its
counterpart that doubles the leading whitespace.

```
:%s/^\(\s*\)\1/\1/
```

A mapping to be constructed for this command needs to follow the same
pattern as the one used in the question (except for the substitution
to execute, of course). To reduce repetition in the definitions, one
can separate the state-preserving code into a small function:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>>    :call PinnedCursorDo('%s/^\s*/&&/')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader><lt> :call PinnedCursorDo('%s/^\(\s*\)\1/\1/')<cr>

function! PinnedCursorDo(cmd)
    let [s, c] = [@/, getpos('.')]
    exe a:cmd
    let @/ = s
    call setpos('.', c)
endfunction
```

Comment: Beautiful! I tried something like this, but I didn't know you could use `\1` in the first substitute block. Simple and effective!

Comment: @PrinceGoulash:  Thanks!  It is somewhat idiomatic kind of patterns.  A remarkable example you are probably aware of, is the regular expression that can be used to test whether a non-negative integer is a prime number.  In Vim script, the test would look like `repeat('1', n) !~ '^1\?$\|^\(1\{-2,}\)\1\+$'`, where `n` is the number in question.

Comment: Thank you, this is really elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your original substitution is this (I have replaced the `/` delimiters with `#` for readability):

```
%s#^\s*#&&#
```

And here is my proposed inverse substitution (take a deep breath...):

```
%s#^\s*#\=matchstr(submatch(0),'^.\{'.string(float2nr(len(submatch(0))/2)).'\}')#
```

Let's say the matched string (`submatch(0)`) contains `n` whitespace characters. What I am doing is calculating half this number (`n/2` = `string(float2nr(len(submatch(0))/2))`) and then extracting that many characters from the match (essentially `matchstr(n/2)`). This ensures we get precisely half the whitespace we started with (which may be a mixture of spaces and tabs).

If you know the whitespace will contain ONLY spaces or ONLY tabs, this could be simplified somewhat, for example:

```
%s#^\s*#\=repeat(" ",indent(".")/2)#
```

On another note, I would recommend reformulating your maps to make them more readable and therefore easier to modify and maintain. My approach would be to define two functions:

```
function! DoubleWS()
    let pos = getpos('.')
    let reg = getreg('@')
    exe '%s/^\s*/&&/e'
    call setreg('@',reg)
    call setpos('.',pos)
endfunction

function! HalfWS()
    let pos = getpos('.')
    let reg = getreg('@')
    exe '%s#^\s*#\=matchstr(submatch(0),"^.\\{".string(float2nr(len(submatch(0))/2))."\}")#e'
    call setreg('@',reg)
    call setpos('.',pos)
endfunction
```

Note that the `get/set` `pos/reg` functions are a much more robust way of maintaining cursor position and register. You can then map these functions as you wish:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>iw :call DoubleWS()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>rw :call HalfWS()<CR>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly. I've also decided to use functions as you suggested. (I'm new to this phase where you actually try to personalize Vim to your needs and tastes, so those are the first functions (outside plugins) that I'm using).

Comment: Welcome! This is where Vim becomes really powerful. These are quite useful functions to learn from, as they introduce variables and executing normal Vim commands. (Note that I edited my answer to remove the `_s2` definitions which are not needed.)

Comment: @GoranNovosel:  Although solving the issue, this implementation sets an example of an over-engineered and repetitive Vim script: The substitute command halving leading whitespace could be more idiomatic and [almost five times shorter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9124761/254635); the state-preserving functions could be [generalized to avoid repetition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9124761/254635).