# How to a posteriori double the indentation levels on all lines of a file in Vim?

Tags: python, vim

I want to change the indentation in all my existing(!) Python files from 2-space to 4-space shift width. Any suggestions how to do this in Vim?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in vim?  Use `find` and `-exec` an `awk` script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `:set ts=4 sw=4` alone will suffice if you use hard tabs (i.e. `noexpandtab`), but I assume that's not the case. It's still possible to utilize this functionality, though, by temporarily setting `noet`:

```
:set noet | retab! | set ts=4 sw=4 et | retab
```

This converts existing spaces to tabs, changes the number of spaces per tab, and reverts to spaces. Note that `retab` may affect sequences of spaces elsewhere in the file.

It's also possible to manually substitute each pair of leading spaces with twice as many:

```
:%s/^\(\(\s\{2}\)\+\)/\1\1/g
```

This approach isn't as generic, though.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I see that my question does not make sense for hardtabs.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best solution for your problem but for one file you can reindent the whole file (if you configured the indentation rules to match your taste):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>

Comment: ... or without visual mode `gg=G`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only used hard tabs (not mixed with spaces), try changing the tabstop and shiftwidth  both to 4 in your vimrc file

Also try looking at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code for some more help with indentation

Comment: @jsbueno you sure? Messing around with those two settings in my own vimrc seems to do the trick on my existing. This may just be a peculiarity on my side though?

Answer (score 0):

To double the indentation levels, one can use the command

```
:%s/^\s*/&&/
```

Comment: To halve indentation, consider the command proposed in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9124761/254635) to the question "[Halve the number of whitespace at the begining of each line in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9118563/254635)".