# Autoformatting python code: dictionaries

Tags: python, formatting

I have a frankly demonic `python` source file, consisting of an endless list of unindented dictionaries.

It's unreadable. I'd like to reformat the file to look like this:

```
[
    {
        'foo'     : 'bar',
        'alpha'   : 'beta',
        'long key': 'bla'
    }

    # 93457823 more dictionaries
]
```

Note the aligned `:`, as well as the human-ready indentation.

Is there a tool that can do this?

Comment: What about pycharm? Maybe you will not get the exact indention you like, but it is a start...

Comment: It won't align the `:`s, but you could use `json.dumps(obj, indent=4)` to do the formatting.

Comment: How complex is the data?  If it's all JSON-serializable you could use JSON to pretty-print it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PEP8 standard defined in Python for how code should be formatted. There is also a tool to enforce this standard "pep8":

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/

From the documentation the following messy code:

```
import math, sys;

def example1():
    ####This is a long comment. This should be wrapped to fit within 72 characters.
    some_tuple=(   1,2, 3,'a'  );
    some_variable={'long':'Long code lines should be wrapped within 79 characters.',
    'other':[math.pi, 100,200,300,9876543210,'This is a long string that goes on'],
    'more':{'inner':'This whole logical line should be wrapped.',some_tuple:[1,
    20,300,40000,500000000,60000000000000000]}}
    return (some_tuple, some_variable)
def example2(): return {'has_key() is deprecated':True}.has_key({'f':2}.has_key(''));
class Example3(   object ):
    def __init__    ( self, bar ):
     #Comments should have a space after the hash.
     if bar : bar+=1;  bar=bar* bar   ; return bar
     else:
                    some_string = """
                       Indentation in multiline strings should not be touched.
Only actual code should be reindented.
"""
                    return (sys.path, some_string)    import math, sys;

def example1():
    ####This is a long comment. This should be wrapped to fit within 72 characters.
    some_tuple=(   1,2, 3,'a'  );
    some_variable={'long':'Long code lines should be wrapped within 79 characters.',
    'other':[math.pi, 100,200,300,9876543210,'This is a long string that goes on'],
    'more':{'inner':'This whole logical line should be wrapped.',some_tuple:[1,
    20,300,40000,500000000,60000000000000000]}}
    return (some_tuple, some_variable)
def example2(): return {'has_key() is deprecated':True}.has_key({'f':2}.has_key(''));
class Example3(   object ):
    def __init__    ( self, bar ):
     #Comments should have a space after the hash.
     if bar : bar+=1;  bar=bar* bar   ; return bar
     else:
                    some_string = """
                       Indentation in multiline strings should not be touched.
Only actual code should be reindented.
"""
                    return (sys.path, some_string)
```

Converts to:

```
import math
import sys


def example1():
    # This is a long comment. This should be wrapped to fit within 72
    # characters.
    some_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 'a')
    some_variable = {
        'long': 'Long code lines should be wrapped within 79 characters.',
        'other': [
            math.pi,
            100,
            200,
            300,
            9876543210,
            'This is a long string that goes on'],
        'more': {
            'inner': 'This whole logical line should be wrapped.',
            some_tuple: [
                1,
                20,
                300,
                40000,
                500000000,
                60000000000000000]}}
    return (some_tuple, some_variable)


def example2():
    return ('' in {'f': 2}) in {'has_key() is deprecated': True}


class Example3(object):

    def __init__(self, bar):
        # Comments should have a space after the hash.
        if bar:
            bar += 1
            bar = bar * bar
            return bar
        else:
            some_string = """
                       Indentation in multiline strings should not be touched.
Only actual code should be reindented.
"""
            return (sys.path, some_string)
```

Comment: Though PEP 8 explicitly forbids aligning elements like OP wants to, this is probably the best option.

Comment: I explicitly want to align them :( key-length is too different

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your .py script to pep8 formating as mentioned here: [Tool to convert Python code to be PEP8 compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328406/tool-to-convert-python-code-to-be-pep8-compliant)