# How can i read these cells from an html code with python web-scraping?

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want scraping the exchange prices informations from this website and after take it into a database: https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok

I need this part of html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="valute"><b>CHF</b></td>
        <td class="valutename">svájci frank</td>
        <td class="unit">1</td>
        <td class="value">284,38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="valute"><b>EUR</b></td>
        <td class="valutename">euro</td>
        <td class="unit">1</td>
        <td class="value">308,54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="valute"><b>USD</b></td>
        <td class="valutename">USA dollár</td>
        <td class="unit">1</td>
        <td class="value">273,94</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thats why i wrote a code, but something wrong with it. How can i fix it, where i have to change it? I need only the "valute", "valutename", "unit" and the "value" dataes. I am working with Python 2.7.13 on Windows 7.

The error message is the next: **"There's an error in your program: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"**

The code is here:

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

table = str(soup)
table = table.split("<tbody>")

list_of_rows = []
for row in table[1].findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
   for cell in row.findAll('td'):
       text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
   list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

print list_of_rows

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Pénznem", "Devizanév", "Egység", "Forintban kifejezett érték"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Comment: Well, you clearly have some indentation problems around `for` loops. You need to use the same amount of spaces...

Comment: Indentation in Python needs to be a multiple of 4 spaces. I suggest you either fix this manually or (preferably) use a code formatter for Python such as [autopep8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328406/tool-to-convert-python-code-to-be-pep8-compliant).

Comment: @Hat Actually, it can be howevermany spaces you want, one is enough, but needs to be applied consistently.

Comment: @098799 Well it *can* be however many spaces you want, but *should* it be? The [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) says to use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `space` problem in your code from the line 18 `for cell in row.findAll('td'):` to line 20 `list_of_cells.append(text)`. Here's the fixed Code :

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mnb.hu/arfolyamok'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('tbody', attrs={'class': 'stripe'})

table = str(soup)
table = table.split("<tbody>")

list_of_rows = []
for row in table[1].findAll('tr')[1:]:
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

print list_of_rows

outfile = open("./inmates.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Pénznem", "Devizanév", "Egység", "Forintban kifejezett érték"])
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

But, after executing this code, you'll face another problem, that's an character encoding error. It'll read "`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file testoasd.py on line 27, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`"

How to fix that? Simple enough... add the shebang `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the very top of your code (1st line). It should fix it.

EDIT :  Just noticed that you're using BeautifulSoup in wrong way and importing it wrong as well. I've fixed the import to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and when using BeautifulSoup, you need to specify a parser as well. So,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

would become :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```