# How to execute "reformat code" of PyCharm via command line (no GUI)?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to script PyCharm to do reformat code without a GUI?

I have a lot of legacy python code, and I would like to clean it automatically.

Comment: If the Pycharm is not a hard requirement, there's [autopep8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328499/2201041)

Comment: @JETM PyCharm is a hard requirement for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run format.bat or format.sh from the IDE installation directory. See the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-formatter.html) for more details on supported options.