# How to Auto-format Code in Python in NPP or Online

Tags: python, pycharm, notepad++, autoformatting

I do most of my Python coding in Notepad++. I would like a way to quickly and easily reformat my code using the default rules from PyCharm - things like spacing,  number of blank lines between functions etc.

I find `black playground` too harsh for my requirements, and opening up PyCharm to paste code and reformat it defeats to purpose of using Notepad++ (for it's lightness).

So do you know of either a plugin for Notepad++ which does this (and I'm not just referring to `Python Indent`), or an online resource which applies PyCharm style formatting to pasted code?

Comment: ```black playground```?

Comment: Try `yapf` or `autopep8`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328499/10025504

Comment: Why not use PyCharm? I used to use Notepad++ but I think PyCharm is much better, and I'm using it at least 5 years. I'm still using also Notepad++ for text files, not Python. And also to convert .sh code files to Unix format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm comes with a **CLI**, like documented here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/command-line-formatter.html.
Alternatively and making the call slightly shorter: parallel to the mentioned there general batch file, you probably also have 'format.bat'. You can integrate this into Notepad++ via the [**F5**] button "Run...":
Put there

```
C:\__YourPyCharmRoot__\bin\format.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

and press the [**Save**] button in this "Run..." dialog to assign a short-cut.

Pressing the newly defined short-cut on a saved and writable Python file should let Notepad++ ask you after a while *(of running PyCharm in Windows cmd.exe)* to reload the changed file .