# Convert entire (Python) file from 2-space indent to 4-space indent

Tags: python, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I regularly work with Python files that are provided to me as templates, which use an indentation of 2. However, I personally prefer working with an indentation width of 4, which is what I've set in my `.vimrc`. However, because of the indentation-sensitivity of Python, the typical `gg=G` way to fix indentation to my preferred indentation width does not work well at all to convert a file to my preferred indentation. Furthermore, just leaving the indentation at a width of 2 screws up with my tabstop settings.

To fix this, what I'd like to do is have some system to convert a 2-space indented file into a 4-space indented file. I don't know what the easiest way to do this would be, but I'm thinking to `vmap <Tab>` to increase the tab width of the selected lines by 1, and `vmap <S-Tab>` to decrease the width by 1. I don't know if there is some built-in method to do this, or if this would require some find/replace rule, but I think having some way to fix the indentation to my preferred width would be useful, given that the autoindent is not smart enough to fix this properly.

Comment: VSCode has that feature built-in.

Comment: The solution is that whoever provides those templates to you needs to do so in a [PEP-8 compliant](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) way. For Python, there's really no discussion about how to indent code. It's either four spaces or wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim:

```
" Convert 2-spaces indent to tabs
:set noexpandtab tabstop=2
:retab!

" Convert tabs to 4-spaces indent
:set expandtab tabstop=4
:retab
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have spaces (instead of tabs) as the indent, it seems like you just need to double the number of leading spaces on each line.

You can use `ggVG` to select your entire file. Pressing : will enter some defaults, from there you can add `s/^(\s*)/\1\1` to double leading spaces in the line.

Explanation of the regex: `^` indicates the beginning of a line. `(\s*)` is a capture group containing any number of spaces. `\1` refers to that capture group, and `\1\1` means to repeat that group twice.

TL;DR: `ggVG=:s/^(\s*)/\1\1`

Comment: To make `:substitute` operate on the entire buffer, you can give it the range `%` which is shorthand for `1,$`. No need for visual mode at all. You can also do without the capture group. Putting it together, all this simplifies your command to `:%s/^\s*/&&/`.

Answer (score 1):

## reindent.py

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1024489/15889930) that deals with this issue.

(From that post) You can use reindent.py, a script provided with your python installation to change python files to use 4-space indents and no hard tab characters.

You can invoke it using

```bash
python3 -m reindent
```

(You can even run it without the `python3 -m`)

And use the help flag for a list of possible flags

```bash
python3 -m reindent --help
```

Install it using pip (`pip install reindent`) if it doesn't exist in your system by default.

### Use within vim

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466936/15889930) by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396422/chris-crook). You can actually use reindent.py within vim:

```
:%! reindent
```

> From the command line it can be used to reindent multiple files (eg all files in a directory, or even recursively down a directory tree).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the answer given by phd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78161435/1256925), I decided to tweak it a bit and write a script that automatically fixes the tab width based on pressing `2<Tab>` for going from 2 to 4 tabs, as well as being able to fix intermingled tab/4-space indentation by pressing `4<Tab`. It makes use of a global variable to prevent the command from running multiple times, but otherwise simply executes the commands given in phd's answer. Pressing a number key and then Tab in normal mode will cause the indentation to be changed from that number to your default tabstop setting.

```
let g:retab_done = 0
function Retab()
    if !v:count || g:retab_done
        return
    endif
    let g:retab_done = 1
    let current_width = &tabstop
    execute "set noexpandtab tabstop=" . v:count
    retab!
    execute "set expandtab tabstop=" . current_width
    retab
    return
endfunction
nmap <Tab> :call Retab()<CR>
```