# Check variable change location in VIM? Or how to set shfitwidth?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

This is not a very simple question.

I found that the "shiftwidth" for python files are set to 4, while I have these at the bottom of my .vimrc:

```
set tabstop=2                                                               
set shiftwidth=2                                                               
set softtabstop=2                                                              
set expandtab
```

The shiftwidth are 2 for all other filetypes; but it's 4 only for python.

I want to know if it's possible to see where a variable (in my case, the shiftwidth) has been changed; if this is not possible when what are the possible locations that this variable is changed..? And is there any way go make the shiftwidth=2 universally... even for the python files? (Although it's also recommended of using 4 spaces for python, but I personally prefer 2)

Comment: I feel like you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158968/changing-vim-indentation-behavior-by-file-type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891805/how-do-i-set-up-different-tab-settings-for-different-languages-in-vim or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011589/vim-python-indentation-not-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:verbose set shiftwidth
```

tells you what's the current value and where it was defined. See `:help :verbose`.

Filetype plugins are sourced after the corresponding `FileType` event was triggered so they will override the options in your `vimrc`.

---

The dirty way to add filetype-specific settings to your config is to add something like this to your `vimrc`:

```
augroup Python
    autocmd!
    autocmd fileType python setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 expandtab
augroup END
```

See `:help :autocmd`.

---

The clean way is to put your desired settings into a custom `ftplugin`.

The file:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
```

Its content:

```
setlocal tabstop=2
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal softtabstop=2
setlocal expandtab
```

Note the use of `setlocal` instead of `set` because you don't want those settings to be applied everywhere.

Comment: For non-binary options, like `'shiftwidth'`, it does not make any difference whether you do `:verbose set shiftwidth` or `:verbose set shiftwidth?`.  I think it is a good habit to add the optional `?` because it _does_ make a difference for binary options.  For example, `:verbose set expandtab` will set the `'expandtab'` option, without telling me anything about where it was previously set or reset.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being set by the built-in `ftplugin` file for Python. If you

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim
```

and search for `shiftwidth`, you’ll probably find it set there to `4`.